# Early results on the Fourier transform

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, harmonic-analysis

Published tables of Fourier transform pairs have been available for many years. One such example is the [paper](https://ia903204.us.archive.org/11/items/bstj7-4-639/bstj7-4-639_text.pdf) by George Campbell in the Bell Systems Technical Journal in 1928. Most such tables simply list the pairs, but I am interested in knowing how I might go about finding the source of a result, by which I mean an earlier paper where the pair and, presumably, its derivation, was published.

Comment: Antecedents of the relation that interests you might also be found  in neighbouring related fields, e.g. in Laplace transforms, of which Fourier transforms are a special case. Also, modern Laplace transforms were a 20th-c. development that replaced Heaviside's calculus, also worth a look.  Maybe also look at https://unacademy.com/content/csir-ugc/study-material/physical-sciences/difference-between-fourier-transform-vs-laplace-transform/ ;  https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/8302/origin-of-the-heaviside-function/ and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/86489 .

Comment: Also, the link given in the question is to an abstract only : the full paper is available at archive.org and has more information. See https://ia903204.us.archive.org/11/items/bstj7-4-639/bstj7-4-639_text.pdf .

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the question to include your link.